# How do I use Stored Procedure to view the entire contents of a table

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

How do I use a stored procedure to view the entire contents of a table in IBM DB2 (and anything else I guess, as SQL scrpting is the same throughout all of them)?

Thanks :)

Comment: SELECT * FROM <qualifiedTableName>

Comment: Why do you need a stored procedure for this? Does `select * from MyTable` not work for you?

Comment: I'm doing stuff at work experience and I've been told I need to use stored procedure :/

Comment: Not for something like what you're describing, you don't.

Comment: It's what I've been told to use, I know I can use `select * from <table>` but ya, I need to try and do it using a stored procedure

Comment: Sadly, SQL Scripting is *not* "the same throughout all of them."  How I wish it were so.  Queries (SELECT) and DML's (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) have a usable core that is implemented pretty much the same on all of them.  The procedural aspects of SQL scripting, however, though functionally similar, vary wildly in their syntactic (and even semantic) details.

Comment: OK, if you MUST use a stored procedure, wrap "select col1, col2, ... from <table>" between "CREATE PROCEDURE" end "END". (You should never user SELECT * when not in interactive mode, but specify each and every column.) This is not the weirdest request I have seen. I had people ask me on how to change column values in a table without using an UPDATE statement, (their boss wouldn't allow them). None of those solutions are efficient or may make any sense to the outside world, but there is always a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In DB2, you must create a cursor that reads data from the table(s) you need and then open it to get the results. I'll give you a sample with no parameters.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MY_SCHEMA.SP_SEL_TABLEX()
RESULT SET 1
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
    DECLARE C_TABLEX CURSOR FOR
        SELECT COL1, COL2
        FROM MY_SCHEMA.TABLEX;
    OPEN C_TABLEX;
END;
```